# Cover screw holes in pvc

Tags: plastic

What's the best way to cover screw holes in pvc? 
I was thinking about filling them,  then covering with a piece of plastic. 
[image]

Comment: I'm partial to white silicone. It really depends on if you're just looking to make it aesthetically pleasing, or if you have a water penetration issue.

Comment: I would like it to look nice bit I don't want to lose the benefits of pvc.

Comment: Short of replacing the whole piece, no amount of fill or cover will make it look as nice as it did sans hole. I would deburr/sand the area where it's puckered and simply fill with white silicone and smooth. This will be almost unnoticeable from 4-6' away, unless you know you're looking for a hole.

Comment: Reinsert (rustproof) screws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BrownRedHawk suggested white silicone will keep water out (paint silicone won't accept paint). White latex caulking is similar to silicone, but it does cover easily with paint. You could also try 2 part white epoxy. This will set to a solid patch that can be sanded smooth and remain rigid and weatherproof. I'd favor the epoxy and once dry paint it with an appliance spray paint to blend it in.

Answer (score 0):

get yourself a little tub of abs to pvc transition cement in white.  using a brush, dab it in the hole and wait a couple of minutes for it to dry.  then repeat until the hole is filled.  you  can stipple it with a fine brush to match the texture around the hole.  you can also add some sawdust from cutting the pvc to the cement to thicken it up to make the hole fill faster.